# How can I access "waiting on" fields in the Asana API?

Tags: asana, asana-api

Asana tasks can be marked as "waiting on" other tasks. I'd like to access this data through the API, but it's either not available or undocumented.

The set of fields returned in an API response can be customised using the `opt_fields` parameter. I've tried adding "waiting," "waitingon" and "waiting_on" to that parameter, with no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi this is not currently supported in the public API for Asana. As a note, if you stumble across an undocumented field they are not supported and may change at any time, so be careful when dealing with such endpoints.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Are there any plans to support it in the future?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of unfortunately.

Comment: To clarify, we _do_ want to support getting and setting dependencies in the future, but there is no timeline when this will be available. I for one vote sooner rather than later, so keep an ear open!